# Include dev branch changes in Build Report off main branch using TFS 2010

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm trying to understand how to produce a report of what's included in a build when we deploy to QA from MAIN.  Our branching scenario is the "Standard Branch Plan" as defined in the ALM Rangers Guidance with MAIN branched to DEV where we do all our work.  We merge back into MAIN and build/deploy from there when a QA release is ready.  However, because all of the WI check-ins occur against our DEV branch the only WI that gets included in the build report off MAIN is our single merge check-in.

In summary, how do I include the list of changesets and associated work items in a MAIN branch build when the workitems and associated changesets exist only in DEV?  Hopefully I'm missing something straightforward before I have to go in and start creating custom reports off DEV.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the report that produced to the QA will contain user stories and bugs only? am I right?, so I would recommended to only associate work times of type task when you check in your code in the Dev Branch, and don't associate bugs or user stories, you only need to associate the task of the user stories and the bugs and when you successfully merge the new change to the main branch you can close the bug or the work items and then queue a build which will produce the QA report that you need

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: I can almost see this doing what we need although atm we don't create a task for a bug.  We checkin directly againt the bug WI.  This is easily fixed and thinking about it that makes more sense as that explains why Bug work items don't estimate fields on them.  However, from where would you easily obtain the list of bugs/stories completed in dev to be marked Resolved when checking in the merge on the main branch?